# 960px is the correct width for website? is percentage better? With only percentage the website is responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I´m trying to develop my first website. And I´m a bit confuse about some points.

I´m developping the html & css and then I want to do my website responsive.

First, I did some research to choose the width for my website, and i found information that the 960px is the best width, So I´m developing my content in 960px! But I have a 17 inch laptop and I have too much white space around the content. Its better do with 1024px for example? Or 960px is better?
And if I do with percentage for example, instead 960px use 70% I´ll resolve the white space, right? This is correct to do?

Second, to my site be responsive I was searching information and I was studying about media queries, but if I use percentage, I dont need to use the media queries, because the site is already responsive, right, or not?
Sorry to bother with this question that may seem simple but I am a beginner and I have this doubt, and maybe with your exprience, you can help me understand better.

Comment: Percentage isn't necessarily responsive, search for something general along the lines of 'responsive website examples' and resize your window to see some of the possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately, the topic is "responsive design" which is pretty broad. You should Google for that. Here's a useful web site: http://responsivedesign.is/

Comment: I already google it! But I dont know if im doing correct with 960px, because I´m getting very white space I guess, so I came here to ask if 960px like I´m doing its correct, and then my idea is to use media queries to adjust to other advices! So im trying to understand if this way is good and correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using percentage, your site will be fluid. To be responsive, use media queries, so you have a site adapted to the screen size, not forcing the content.
A little about CSS Media Queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: hmm, thanks!So maybe i can continue with 960px, and then use media queries to adjust to other devices?

Comment: That's right. I indicate also take a look on "mobile first".